# Django UserCreationForm's fields doesn't show up

Tags: python, django, django-admin

```
class UserRegForm(forms.ModelForm):
......

  class Meta:
      model = get_user_model() # model has: username, email, full_name, is_admin/is_staff/etc.
      fields = ('username', 'email', 'full_name',)
```

And yet, when going into Django admin and pressing "new user", it asks for username and password only... And, when I create a user like that and try to edit/change it, the 'email' field is completely empty (which is the username_field)...

Why?

Comment: Please note that if you are using `django` `user` model, then there's no such field called `fulll_name`. Maybe what you want to put is `first_name` and last_name` fields... By calling the `get_full_name` method, you'll get the full name of the `user` object.

Comment: It's a custom user model(abstract).

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of declaring the model is:

from yourapp.models import Yourmodel

.....
class Meta:
model = Yourmodel
fields = ....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So basically it's advised to use the model itself instead of the ger_user_model method? I'll try that tomorrow and drop an update.